# OctoberCMS - how can I use one url-slug for different pages?

Tags: octobercms

There's a page with url

```
url = "/:category"
```

I need also a page with

```
url = "/:brand"
```

The logic which is currently used is to have:

- a page *1-page.htm*
- a partial *catalog.htm*
- a partial *brand.htm*

At *1-page.htm* we define what type of page actually is (through onStart() section or some component) and render the needed chunk

```
{% if type == 'category'%}
    {% partial "catalog" %}
{% elseif type == 'brand' %}
    {% partial "brand" %}
{% endif %}
```

So how can I set up the CMS to avoid having *1-page.htm*, *2-page.htm* etc having routing logic and be able to have ***pages*** *catalog.htm* and *brand.htm*?
I'd like to get rid of such kind of routing pages defining what partial to render and move routing logic somewhere to *routes.php* of a plugin.

Of course http redirects or web-server tuning are rather too extreme variants

F.E. user comes with *example.com/phones*. At routes.php I define a page *catalog.htm*
When user comes with *example.com/samsung*, I'd like to be able to use a page *catalog.htm*

Comment: Do you have models for Brand & Category? And How you have given the link to these routes?

Comment: please tell me do you have?

Comment: hmm question seems having little problem - like -> `single url can ONLY point to single page` - as its `static` so we always recieve `same url` and `can not expect it to be redirect/render different page`.. we must provide some details with URL for redirection/render different page. so what we can do we can create multiple URL and it can point to single page. where all that url can have info how to render that single page .. like `type info` like that ... OR may be you can add some of your example what you want so we can answer it in better way

Comment: @ChiragPatel yes, there are models but I doubt they could help.

Comment: @HardikSatasiya I can not change URL anyway according SEO demanding. They have their own vision for url structure. It's pity October doesn't provide any instruments for having pages like category.htm and brand.htm serving same url like /:blablabla
Seems like a Plugin essence should be able choose what page to be required if there are several candidates for an url.

Comment: hmm but if you think logically you need some thing to put in condition so you can identify which page you want to show right means .. your condition in `onStart() ` which can set `type = 'category'` or `type == 'brand'` but also there you need some condition to do that if you dont mind can you share how you desire to set `type = 'somethig'` ... so i can help you on that regard